# How does one figure out how big to make an object to make it scale to fit a Curve Modifier perfectly?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

Suppose I want to make a flat surface curved using the Curve Modifier; how do I do this so that the flat surface follows the curve from end-to-end exactly?  I can hackily scale the flat surface along the curve but then it flies off the end of the curve and the vertices on the curve are all arbitrarily placed!  Is there some sort of "Stretch to Fit" option for the object having the Curve Modifier being applied to it?

This is my curve from above:
[image: Curve from Above]

This is my flat plane I want to have mapped to the curve:
[image: Flat Plane from Front]

You can see that the flat plane is the same length as the curve from the front view.  However, when the following Curve Modifier is added to it, it shrinks and for some reason, the 45-degree-angles lines become curved!

[image: Curve Modifier]

[image: Flat Plane from Front with Curve Modifier]

[image: Flat Plane with Curve Modifier (3D)]

The origin of the curve and the plain are in the same place (I was having other weird issues before having done that).  I've subdivided the plain into 16 faces per square so that it can curve and used "Set Smooth" on all of those faces).  What do I need to do to stop the plain from orthographically shrinking laterally when it uses the Curve Modifier?

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/